# Responsive CSS Dropdown Navigation issues in IE8 and IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, navigation

Here is my page HTML.  Below is my CSS for the main navigation styles.  IE7 does not display the padding, hover or drop down items.  IE8 padding is good, hover works, but drop downs do not display.  My code may be a big mess- probably a lot of unnecessary stuff.  I've been working with all sorts of suggestions to no avail.  So anyone willing to take the time and help me resolve my navigation issue?  I will be so incredibly appreciative!  I'm hoping there's something obvious here to someone who is much more knowledgeable than myself. Here is the live site. http://www.tortolasportsclub.com/  Also, my animation's down level poster image loads with scroll bars (Adobe Edge Animate).  Not sure what's going on there. Have been unable to find a solution for that also.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<title></title>
<link href="css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="home">
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg"></div>
    <div id="register">
      <span class="button"></span>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="index.html" id="homemenu">Home</a>      </li>
      <li><a href="about/index.html" id="aboutmenu">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="about/committee.html">Committee Members</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="sports/index.html" id="sportsmenu">Sports</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="sports/squash.html">Squash</a>          </li>
          <li><a href="sports/tennis.html">Tennis</a></li>
          <li><a href="sports/gym.html">Gym</a></li>
          <li><a href="sports/multipurpose.html">Multipurpose</a></li>


          <li><a href="sports/junior-programs.html">Junior Programs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="clubhouse/index.html" id="clubhousemenu">Clubhouse</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="clubhouse/menu.html">Restaurant Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="news/events.html">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="clubhouse/staff.html">Staff</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="news/index.html" id="newsmenu">News</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="news/events.html">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="news/news.asp">Submit News</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="sponsors/index.html" id="sponsorsmenu">Sponsors</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="sponsors/become-a-sponsor.html">Become a Sponsor</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.asp" id="contactmenu">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div id="figure"><object id="bannerframe" data="animation/tsc-index-banner.html" width="100%" height="100%"><embed href="tsc-index-banner.html" width="100%" height="100%"></embed></object>
    <div id="blktxtbar"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="section">
  <div id="article1"></div>
  <div id="article3"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer-nav"></div>
<div id="footer-nav2"></div>
  <div id="footer-co"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/selectnav.min.js"></script>
<script>selectnav('menu'); </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        var resizeObject = function() {
            var object = $('#bannerframe');
            var width = object.width(); 
            var ratio = 350.0 / 960.0;
            var height = Math.floor(width * ratio) + 'px';
            object.height(height);
        };

        $(window).resize(resizeObject);
        resizeObject();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

#nav {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font: 1.1em Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#nav ul {
    clear:left;
    float:right;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    right: 50%;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav ul li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    width: 6.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background: #FFF;
}
#nav ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
    display:block;
    right: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:1px solid #224b09;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    background-color: #36780f;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#36780f), color-stop(100%, #005900));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #005900);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #005900);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #005900);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #005900);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #005900);


    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#36780f, endColorstr=#005900);
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
#nav ul li.active a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #4ba614;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4ba614), color-stop(100%, #030));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4ba614, #030);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4ba614, #030);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4ba614, #030);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4ba614, #030);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4ba614, #030);

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#4ba614, endColorstr=#030);
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
#nav ul li:hover a, #nav ul li.hover a /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #36780f;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#36780f), color-stop(100%, #000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #000);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #000);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#36780f, endColorstr=#000);
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    left: 1;
    padding-top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    right: auto;
    font-size: .9em;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    padding-top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    left: auto;
    margin: 0;
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#nav ul ul li a,
#nav ul li.active li a,
#nav ul li:hover ul li a,
#nav ul li.hover ul li a { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #36780f;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#36780f), color-stop(100%, #005900));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #005900);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #005900);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #005900);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #005900);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #005900);

    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#36780f, endColorstr=#005900);
    text-align: left;
    line-height:1.4em;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li.active ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li.hover ul li a:hover { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
    font-size:1em;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #36780f;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#36780f), color-stop(100%, #000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #000);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #36780f, #000);

    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#36780f, endColorstr=#000);
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul.last {
   left:auto; 
   right:0; 
}
#nav ul li:hover ul,
#nav ul li.hover ul { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: You're posting incomplete code samples, with vague descriptions of your the issues you are experiencing.  Don't expect anyone to be able to properly help you.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first post.  I put all my css for my navigation menu.  What more is needed?

Comment: The HTML markup for the navigation is as equally important as the CSS.  Also provide a working example so people don't have to rebuild your scenario.  Don't expect us to read through 100 lines of CSS and know exactly what the problem is without seeing it in action.